# Globally register styles but enqueue them selectively

Tags: plugins, themes, admin, css

I am trying to get my theme registered stylesheets in plugin, the purpose is I want to get all stylesheets in my plugin and then manipulate those registered styles.

stylesheets registered via

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_register_styles', 1);

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_styles', 5);
```

and as you already know this action doesn't get fired in backend, so I want a hookable / callable way so it gets enqueued and I can modify / manipulate for my needs and resave them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the stylesheets registered in the backend, use the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) action.

```
function wp94156_register_styles() {
    wp_register_style(
        'your-stylesheet',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/your-stylesheet.css',
        $deps, // optional
        $version // optional
    );
    // since you only want it registered, we won't enqueue it
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp94156_register_styles' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Pat J, but I need to get theme registered stylesheets (it can be any stylesheet parent theme, child theme) and I want to get them as on frontend we can get with global $wp_styles, so I want something similar in backend, I have explored lots of plugins but none of them seems to be useful for my needs.